# Find a example in $L^2$, nonempty closed but contains no element of smallest norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

As we know in Hilbert Space, a nonempty closed convex set always contains a element of smallest norm. I wanna find a example to show the convexity in some way is necessary. No loss of generosity, for simplification, let the domain be $[0,1]\subset R$.

Thanks.

Comment: "No loss of generosity"?!

Comment: I think the constructions of the examples may be similar in different domains.

Comment: I think a closed, bounded set on R will always have a smallest element. This must concide with the infimum. (to see this, take a sequence of elements approaching the inf, by closure, the limit is in the set) convex here means it has to be an interval. This is trivial. you need a different domain.

Comment: Thanks, the link is actually an valid example.