# A non-empty, closed subset of $L^2([0,1])$ that does not contain a vector of smallest norm

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

Would anyone be so kind to tell me if my answer to a problem is correct? Thank you! Happy new year!

The problem appeared on the UW-Madison Analysis Qual in January 2016.

Give an example of a non-empty closed subset of $L^2([0,1])$ that does not contain a vector of smallest norm.

I know an example that works. It's $\frac{n+1}{n}e_n$ where $e_n$ is an orthonormal basis for the $L^2([0,1])$ space. You can choose $e_n=\sqrt{2}\sin(n\pi x)$.

**What I would like to know is the following:**

My initial guess was $\{\sqrt{n+1}\chi_{[0,1/n]} : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $\chi_{[0,1/n]}$ is the characteristic function of $[0,1/n]$. I thought this example worked because the $L^2$ norm of each term is $\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}$, which is decreasing in $n$, so the smallest norm is never achieved. **Does this example work? Is the set closed?**

I have done some computation and realized that the distances between arbitrary terms does go to zero, which means we can't use the same argument as the orthonormal basis example.

Similar questions have been asked on this website:

[Find a example in $L^2$, nonempty closed but contains no element of smallest norm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545325/find-a-example-in-l2-nonempty-closed-but-contains-no-element-of-smallest-nor?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Minimum principle in Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92497/minimum-principle-in-hilbert-space)

[counter example of minimum principle in incomplete inner product space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985496/counter-example-of-minimum-principle-in-incomplete-inner-product-space?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92497/minimum-principle-in-hilbert-space (replace the specific $e_n$ in the answer with an orthonormal basis for $L^2[0,1]$).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I had actually looked at that page and figured out that $e_n(x)=\sqrt{2}sin(n\pi x)$. I was just wondering why my example $\sqrt{n+1}\chi_{[0,1/n]}$ doesn't work.

Comment: Good question. It might help to edit the question to be slightly more specific: not to ask for a general example (which you know exists), but to ask if your specific set is an example (i.e., "is [this specific set] closed or not").  Without engaging in computation, I don't see the answer.  (The advantage of using orthonormal vectors in a general example is that it simplifies computing distances between arbitrary pairs of them)

Comment: Makes sense. Just edited!

Comment: Also, I think the $2$-norm for your example should be $\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}$. You seem to not have the square root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is closed. Assume a sequence from $\{\sqrt{n+1}\chi_{[0,1/n]}\}$ were convergent in $L^2$ and denote the limit by $g$. The sequence must have a subsequence that converges to $g$ a.e. Suppose $g$ is not in the set $\{\sqrt{n+1}\chi_{[0,1/n]}\}$. Since $\sqrt{n+1}\chi_{[0,1/n]}$ converges to zero function a.e. as $n\to\infty$, any non-constant convergent sequence must converge to the zero function a.e. So $g = 0$ a.e. However, $||\sqrt{n+1}\chi_{[0,1/n]}||_2>1$ and $||g||_2=0$, so there can't be an $L^2$ convergence. Contradiction. $g$ is in the set and the set is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer works! What you can show is that with your set denoted as $\{y_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is that any non-constant convergent sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ that is a subset of your set must eventually satisfy for all $m$, there exists an $M$ so that $\{x_n\}_{n \ge M} \subset \{y_n\}_{n \ge m}$, and further that for all $y_0$ in the set and $\epsilon>0$, $\|y_n - y_0\| > \epsilon$ for all $n \ge m$ for some $m$. These can be combined to show that any subsequence of your set that is convergent must be eventually constant.

Comment: Thank you! I like this solution.

Comment: Why is it not closed? I think what the accepted answer shows is any $L^2$ limit of a sequence must be an element of the set. Isn't that showing closed-ness?

Comment: @Aghbab Deleted the comment. I got confused by his wording; I thought he was proving the opposite result by contradiction based on his first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Your example does work. If $K\subset\Bbb N$ is an infinite  subset along which $\{f_n\}$ converges in $L^2$ to some $g\in L^2$, then there is a further subsequence along which the convergence is a.e, and this implies that $g=0$ a.e. But this is impossible because $\|g\|_2=0\not=1=\lim_{n\in K}\|f_n\|_2$. In short, the only convergent sequences to be extracted from your set $F:=\{f_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ are eventually constant, so $F$ is closed.