# Is convexity necessary for the existence of a shortest-norm vector?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples

There's a well-known result in the theory of Hilbert spaces, namely the projection on closed convex sets:

> If $C$ is a nonempty closed convex set in a Hilbert space $H$, then there exists a unique vector in $C$ that has the smallest norm.

Now, I understand the oft-stated proof which uses the parallelogram law. However, I was expecting that convexity is required only for the proof of uniqueness (one easily thinks of annuli around the origin) and that existence was a result only of closed-ness. But even the existence argument in the proof uses convexity.

Thus I ask of a counterexample to my intuition, namely a Hilbert space in which a closed nonempty set has no vector of least norm.

---

Okay, so I can understand that if the space is infinite-dimensional, then we can take the set containing $(1 + 1/n)e_n$ where $e_n$'s are orthonormal.

This raises the question: What about finite-dimensional spaces?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A non-empty, closed subset of $L^2([0,1])$ that does not contain a vector of smallest norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4346085/a-non-empty-closed-subset-of-l20-1-that-does-not-contain-a-vector-of-sma) (the OP and discussion link to other examples)

Comment: @leslietownes I have made an edit, thus looking for a finite-dimensional example.

Comment: Your question was rightly closed as a duplicate. Your new question should be edited as a new post, not as a later edit of this one.

Comment: That said, note that in $\Bbb R^n$, it $C$ is a closed nonempty set then $C\cap \bar B(0,R)$ is compact and, for $R$ large enough, still nonempty, so it will contain a vector of shortest norm.